# ReadXmlSchema not bringing columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ado.net

I have an export/import tool that writes and reads records from a stored-procedure to a .xml file. It was working fine, until I changed the proc: I added a single new column in the proc resultset by joining the original table to a new one.

So far, the Export works fine, but when I try to import the file generated, it's raising the `datatable does not match to any datatable in source` error.

This is a real .xml file I'm trying to import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="RISKS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="RiskID" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="ProjectID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ProjectPhase" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CompanyID" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="SchemaID" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="Sequence" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="Probability" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="Impact" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="RiskScore" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RiskStatus" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="RBSNodeID" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="ActionCount" type="xs:short" />
                <xs:element name="Created" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element name="LimitDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Changed" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element name="ChangedBy" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="PublishedBy" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ExpectedCostValue" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlannedCostPendingActions" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlannedCostMonitoringActions" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlannedCostFinishedActions" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RealCostFinishedActions" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlannedCostSum" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ProjectedCostSum" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="IsImported" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element name="IsRealized" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element name="CustomCode" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ExternalCustomCode" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Description">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="2147483647" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Description2" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="2147483647" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="AdditionalInformation" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="2147483647" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="WorkPackage" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="2147483647" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ExpectedCostReason" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="2147483647" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ProjectNickname">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <RISKS>
    <RiskID>1001</RiskID>
    <ProjectID>1</ProjectID>
    <ProjectPhase>1</ProjectPhase>
    <CompanyID>1</CompanyID>
    <SchemaID>2</SchemaID>
    <Sequence>126</Sequence>
    <Probability>1</Probability>
    <Impact>1</Impact>
    <RiskScore>1</RiskScore>
    <RiskStatus>0</RiskStatus>
    <RBSNodeID>45</RBSNodeID>
    <ActionCount>0</ActionCount>
    <Created>2015-04-23T22:11:08.723-03:00</Created>
    <LimitDate>2015-04-23T00:00:00-03:00</LimitDate>
    <Changed>2015-04-23T22:11:08.807-03:00</Changed>
    <ChangedBy>1073741823</ChangedBy>
    <ExpectedCostValue>0.0000</ExpectedCostValue>
    <PlannedCostPendingActions>0.0000</PlannedCostPendingActions>
    <PlannedCostMonitoringActions>0.0000</PlannedCostMonitoringActions>
    <PlannedCostFinishedActions>0.0000</PlannedCostFinishedActions>
    <RealCostFinishedActions>0.0000</RealCostFinishedActions>
    <PlannedCostSum>0.0000</PlannedCostSum>
    <ProjectedCostSum>0.0000</ProjectedCostSum>
    <IsImported>false</IsImported>
    <IsRealized>false</IsRealized>
    <CustomCode>RR.PROJ_A.0126</CustomCode>
    <Description>asd</Description>
    <Description2>asd</Description2>
    <AdditionalInformation />
    <WorkPackage />
    <ExpectedCostReason />
    <ProjectNickname>PROJ_AA</ProjectNickname>
  </RISKS>
</NewDataSet>
```

This is the code I'm using to import the .xml file:

```
_tbl = new DataTable();
_tbl.ReadXmlSchema("MyFile.xml");
_tbl.TableName = "RISKS";
_tbl.ReadXml("MyFile.xml");
```

After I read the schema, and before I try to load the file content, I can see the table columns are null, so the `ReadXmlSchema` didn't read correctly the schema, but I don't know why, since the `ReadXmlSchema` didn't raises any error.

The new column is the `ProjectNickname`, the last one.

**EDIT**

Guys, I found out the real problem here, it wasn't neither the `ReadXmlSchema` nor the XML file: actually this code is called inside a loop that extract 5 entries from a .zip file. These entries were supposed to be ordered by a specific criteria, and the .zip that crashed the program had the entries in a different order. So the code above reads the schema from a table `RISKCOMMENTS`, set the table name to `RISK`, and when it tries to read the xml, it obviously crashes...

Comment: Did you try _tbl.ReadXml("MyFile.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);?  There are 7 options : //Default,Auto = 0,ReadSchema = 1,IgnoreSchema = 2,InferSchema = 3,DiffGram = 4,Fragment = 5,InferTypedSchema = 6,

Comment: I see `ExternalCustomCode` is missing from the xml data portion

Comment: @Geewers, the `ExternalCustomCode` is not a mandatory field, it's ok if it does not appears in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the overload on ReadXml():

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataTable.BeginLoadData();
dataSet.ReadXml("MyFile.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
dataTable.EndLoadData();
```

For more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also make sure all of the required elements are in your XML per XSD.

Comment: Where does `dataTable` come from? After initializing the dataSet it has no tables...